# Validate against duplicate field from database in oop php

Tags: php, oop, validation

I am somewhat new to object oriented programming in php. And currently working on interface project. I have interne_nummer field which is coming from database. And i need to validate this field to check that there should not be duplicate interne_nummer field allowed but not getting idea of how to validate it. I have  posted a small code where i want to validate for interne_nummer field as everything else is running fine in my code.

```
 case 'interne_nummer':
 {
    /* validate against valid interne_nummer */
    $this->interne_nummer = trim(strval($value));
    break;
 }
```

For example there are some float fields for which i am validating it as follows and its working fine:

```
 case 'schlussrate':            
            {
                /* @todo validate as float*/
                try {
                    $this->{$name} = $this->getFloatValue($value);
                } catch (Execption $e) {
                    $this->{$name} = '';
                    // Throw Exception to higher Level
                    throw new Exeption("Field '".$name."': ".$e->getMessage());
                }               
                break;
             }

 protected function getFloatValue($value) {     
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
        return floatval($value);    
    }
    throw new \Exeption("Value not allowed '".$value."'");
 }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php, actually. Use a unique key in your database?

Comment: If that field is coming from a db, why cant you just mark it `UNIQUE` and let the db take care, that no duplicates exist?

Comment: yes i know that is simple to simply make it unique in database but the thing is i cant make any change in database as i have restriction not to touch company database so thats why i have to validate the field from code. I think using try catch i can validate it but dont know how to do that

Comment: Then run a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE interne_nummer = $value` and see if record already exists. I really don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: If you can't do that, then just query to see if a value exists with that number?

Comment: Well It doesn't relate to OOP!

Comment: i am sorry but cant i validate it using try catch without making changes in tht query. As i have mentioned i am working in interface project and its big project and there are more than 200 fields so its quiet difficult for me to make changes in the query

Comment: @ajay you can't modify the database, you can't modify the SQL, what exactly is your job? This sounds ridiculous.

Comment: Please check the updated question so that you will get idea of what i want to say and how i want to validate it

Comment: @ajay I am getting confused now. So you want to check if the number already exists in the database, but you don't want to check if it exists in the database? How are you going to find out if it exists or not if you don't call it???

Comment: Why r u confused ? i have explained everythnig to you. That was just an example to get you an idea. I dont want to check intern_nummer field to check it is exist or not but want to check in such way to check for duplicate entry. So i will be having separate function for intern_nummer field to check whether there are duplicate entry or not for this field and if it is then throw an exception

Comment: @ajay so how do you visualize checking for duplicate entry without running a query ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a function like this a try:

```
public function exists($detail, $table, $column, $value) {        
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows >= 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So when you call the function it could look like this:

```
// "SELECT `interne_nummer` FROM `workers` WHERE `interne_nummer` = '$interne_nummer_val'"
if($class->exists('interne_nummer', 'workers', 'interne_nummer', '$interne_nummer_val')) {
  echo 'Number exists';
} else {
  echo 'Number doesn\'t exists';
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but please check the updated question of how i am validating float fields without making changes in the query thats how i want to validate interne_nummer field for duplicate entry through code

Comment: @ajay If you change the function you showed getFloatValue() to also use this function. You don't change the query you only add a new function that uses a new query. Which btw. can validate many fields very easy

Comment: Actually the field intern_nummer is very important field and its the only field which i want to validate for duplicate entry as it works like primary key in database.

Comment: @ajay but still you can replace that function with this function. If you do so it should work

Comment: Cant you please tell me in such a way how to do it as given in the example ? I dont want to use any query please as this file is only used for checking validation for my fields and i dont want to use any query in this file. Just want to use separate fucntion to check for duplicate entry . Do you know any method for this ? Like for validation of integer values  i have is_numeric () methods

Comment: If you have this function in another file than you can simply call it with `exists()` or if you put it in another class you call it like I showed it in the example